# Merge 2 object lists in java

Tags: list, arraylist, data-structures, merge, tobjectlist

i have two lists `listA` and `listB` of type object

`ListA[name=abc, age=34, weight=0, height=0]` data collected from excel sheet

`ListB[name=null, age=0, weight=70, height=6]` data collected from database

Now i want to combine both the lists into a single list

`MergedList[name=abc, age=34, weight=70, height=6]`

**Note**: my obj class has more than 15 properties so adding each property one by one using `getProperty()` will be time-consuming.is there a better way?

Comment: But what about other properties like age weight and height?? My problem is that my object class has around 20 properties i cant assign one by one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert them to a Map where the key is the name of the object ( you denoting the elements as *name=abc* suggests they are name/value pairs ).

```java
Map<String,MyMysteriousObject> converted = list.stream().collect( Collectors.toMap(MyMysteriousObject::getName, Function.identity() ) );
```

( replace the *getName* with what ever function you use to get the name of your object )

And then just merge the maps. How to merge maps is described [here](https://www.baeldung.com/java-merge-maps) for example.

While at it, consider replacing the List with Map in your entire code. Will surely save a lot of work elsewhere too.

But if you have to have a list again, just `List<MyMysteriousObject> resultList = new ArrayList<>(resultMap);`